# How to tell if a POST request contains files for uploading in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, sails.js

I use `sails.js` for creating a backend, and it supports posting text and uploading file/image same time in one of my controller methods. Because of the business logics, I need to tell if a POST request to this controller method contains file for uploading or not.

To upload files, I use the build-in `Skipper` [module](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) in sails.js and use the `file` field in the `req` parameters. For example, if I need to upload images, I put `images` field in the request going to the backend/sails.js:

```
req.file('images').Upload({...});
```

I tried to use `req.file('images')` to examine if the incoming request contains files to upload by following, but it does not work - request without uploading files still gives `req.file('images') = true`:

```
if (!!req.file('images')) { // this turns out to be true regardless of uploading file or not
            return uploadToS3(req, 'images');
        }

sails.log.info('creating entity without uploading file');
return createEntityWithoutImage(req.params.all());
```

Any idea how to tell if a POST request contains file to upload?

Answer (score 1):

You can check number of files that the user uploaded by using:

`req.file('images')._files.length`

This is undocumented feature of skipper:

https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/blob/master/standalone/Upstream/Upstream.js#L51

So it can be decpreate in future versioln. So be sure, that you not upgrade the module without testing it first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I got this error: `Error: EMAXBUFFER: An Upstream (`NOOP_images`) timed out before it was plugged into a receiver. It was still unused after waiting 4500ms. You can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` option.`. I guess when you call `req.file('images')._files.length`, the `req.file()` function is executed, leading to the above error if no file input is received within that time window.

Comment: I think I had the same problem long time ago and I used this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185223/sails-js-how-to-know-if-the-request-contains-a-file-to-upload/31651551#31651551
But it probably don't work anymore (got negative points on this answer :( If it works for you, please upvote ;)